# How do I find the full URL to an Structure managed entry via the regular channel loop?

Tags: structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="product" disable="member_data|categories|trackbacks|pagination|category_fields" rdf="off" dynamic="off" status="Open"}
     <url>
        <loc>{page_url} {title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{gmt_edit_date format="{DATE_W3C}"}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</urlset>
```

Comment: Seems my code is getting stripped out here, so here's a pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/utqQEXGG

{title} works
{page_url} is empty

Comment: Just have to use the code formatting button :P There you go.

Answer (score 1):

`{page_url}` should work; seems like an odd question, but, are you sure entries in the product channel have URLs? If they're managed by Structure as "Assets," they wouldn't have a URL, for example.